# Wierd XML not being parsed

Tags: xml, parsing, xquery, libxml2, libxml-js

I'm facing a strange problem with parsing xml with `libxmljs`.
It's not my first XML to parse and I've done quite a number of them, but [this one](http://pastebin.com/mcpH4Ehk) acts really strange.

I'm having these namespaces:

```
var nsUri = {
        "xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
        "xmlns:SIG": "https://sigtest.tais.ru/SIG/"
    };
```

And doing this:

```
var xmlDoc = xmljs.parseXml(providerResponse);
var ShopOptions = xmlDoc.find('//ShopOptions/ShopOption',self.provider.nsUri);
```

Which results in zero length array. I'm trying to go for different xquery stings: `*/ShopOption`, `//ShopOption` etc. But nothing works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ShopOption/>` element inherits the namespace of its `<SIG_Response/>` ancestor, `https://sigtest.tais.ru/SIG/`. You already declared that namespace, but also have to use it.

```
//SIG:ShopOptions/SIG:ShopOption
```

The other two queries you tried also don't use namespaces. `*/ShopOption` looks for all second-level `<ShopOption/>` children starting at the current context, probably the root here; `//ShopOption` also searches for elements without namespace.